# Tabstop in rmarkdown for word output

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

Is it possible to write a tabstop directly in a rmarkdown document with word as output? I tried \t but it did not work.

Here is a minimal example for a rmarkdown document with a word output:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

## R Markdown

Is it possible to write a tabstop directly in a rmarkdown document with word as output? I tried \t but it did not work.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a tabstop by using the HTML entity `&#9;` for a tab:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

## R Markdown

Is it possible to write a tabstop directly in a rmarkdown document with word as output? I tried &#9; but it did not work.
```

[image]